# Синтаксическая роль краткого причастия

Tags: синтаксис

***Чернеет лес, теплом разбуженный, весенней сыростью объят.***

Мы знаем, что краткое причастие в предложении всегда сказуемое.

Но в данном предложении конструкция *весенней сыростью объят* воспринимается как определение, выраженное причастным оборотом, следующим за однородным причастным оборотом *теплом разбуженный*. *Чернеет лес (какой?)весенней сыростью объят (=объятый).*

Вопрос: **Может ли причастный оборот употребляться в роли определения, но с кратким причастием в качестве главного слова? Или краткое причастие следует воспринимать и в этом случае как сказуемое, а *весенней сыростью* - дополнением?**

Для себя я пока объясняю такое использование краткого причастия более широкими синтаксическими возможностями поэтической речи по сравнению с речью прозаической.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вопрос: **Может ли причастный оборот употребляться в роли определения,
>   но с кратким причастием в качестве главного слова?**

**Может.**

> В художественной литературе встречаются распространённые и одиночные
>   определения, выраженные краткими формами имён прилагательных и
>   краткими страдательными причастиями, например:
>
> *На берегу пустынных волн стоял он, **дум великих полн**, и вдаль глядел* (Пушк.).
>
> *Перейду я в мир иной, **убаюкан лёгким звоном лёгкой радости земной*** (Тург.).
>
> *Как барс пустынный, **зол и дик**, я пламенел, визжал, как он* (Лерм.).

***"Современный русский язык. Синтаксис"*** под ред. Е.М. Галкиной-Федорук; изд. МГУ, 1957

Answer (score 2):

Вы абсолютно правы, это причастный оборот - обособленное определение.

Это не краткое причастие, это усечённая форма причастия в поэтической речи, такая же, как усечённое прилагательное:( примечание к «Евгению Онегину») «В явь богиню благосклонну Зрит восторженный Пиит, Что проводит ночь бессонну, Опершися на гранит».  Это старая традиция. У Никитина, например:

На бугре трава зелёная

Спит, вся искрами обрызгана,

Пылью розовой осыпана

Да каменьями унизана.

Детям можно сказать, что это устаревшее использование кратких форм причастий вместо полных.

Comment: _"Это не краткое причастие, это усечённая форма причастия в поэтической речи, такая же, как усечённое прилагательное…"_ ===  Людмила! У Пушкина в приведённых Вами примерах _благосклонну, бессонну_ -- усечённые прилагательные. Но вот у Никитина **в обособленных** определениях -- краткие причастия (не усечённые!). Усекаются окончания, но не часть суффикса. Вы пример с Никитиным из  учебника взяли?